# Google maps v3 API Error

Tags: google-maps

I am using Google Maps v3 API on one of my websites and everything was working fine. However quite suddenly since yesterday every time i try to access the map page i 'm getting this error:

```
Error: Script terminated by timeout at: 
f@http://maps.googleapis.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/32/1a/map.js:1:175 
next@http://maps.googleapis.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/32/1a/map.js:2:310 
hx@http://maps.googleapis.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/32/1a/map.js:7:457
_.jl.prototype.Yb<@http://maps.googleapis.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/3/1a/map.js:54:163 
Uy@http://maps.googleapis.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/32/1a/map.js:38:313
Xy/<@http://maps.googleapis.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/32/1a/map.js:39:307
```

Any idea why is this happened ?

Comment: Same for us. I've read all the answers and it looks like we all have same problem. The fact is that we've seen that previously in some cases, we sent null in lat and lng (due to an internal issue) and Maps API worked well, but recently it's not accepting null anymore, so if freezes and waits indefinitely for a response. Could it be your case as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the issue with Latitude and Longitude.

Latitude and Longitude should be of 'float' numbers. If we pass other datatypes to it, it freezes the browser as it is waiting for google response with wrong datatype.

```
function drawMap( lat, lng ) { lat = parseFloat(lat); lng = parseFloat(lng); if ( ! isNaN( lat ) && ! isNaN( lng ) ) // Before sending it to google let check if they are valid values
{
    var mapOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(44.5452, -78.5389),
        zoom: 5
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('vehicle_country_region_from_map'),   mapOptions);
}}
```

Answer (score 3):

How does your code look like?
Today, I realized I had the same problem (it's been working for the last couple of months) and came here for answers, but ultimatly stumbled upon a solution myself.

Old code:

```
<script>
    function initMap(lat,lon) {
        var uluru = {lat: parseFloat(lat), lng: parseFloat(lon)};
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 4,
        center: uluru
    });
  }
```

Changed to:

```
<script>
    function initMap(lat,lon) {
        var uluru = {lat: lat, lng: lon};
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 4,
        center: uluru
    });
  }
```

Notice that after the change, I parse my latidue & longitude strings to floats *before* calling the initMap function.

Comment: This helped to find my problem. But I think you've put your answers the wrong way round?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and searched for answers, but couldn't find any. atlast made a workaround. this may help you to solve problem temporarily.

before my code was like

```
          script.src = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&callback=initialize";
```

modified it to

```
    script.src = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&callback=initMap&key=YOUR_API_KEY";
```

you can generate api key from https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key and follow code of initMap( ) as like in https://developers.google.com/maps/

this fixed my problem.

Comment: Still working on it. As for your code I 'm not quite sure but i think that the sensor parameter is no longer required.

Comment: Correct - the sensor parameter is not needed.  Also, you are using the "experimental" version of the code library - if you want to use a fixed version you should change the v=3.exp to a set value, e.g. v=3.30 - this will stop the library "changing on its own". More details here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/versions

Answer (score 0):

Ok, found my problem:
(The problem was causing the browser page to freeze with the errors in the original question)

Original code:

```
if($('#map_canvas').length) {

    //var lat = 53.8683;
    //var lng = 0.5;

    // instantiate geocoder
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    // create new latitude / longitude object
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng);

    // set map options
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 5,
        center: latlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    // display map
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
    // show the map div
    $('#map_canvas').show();
}
```

Uncommented these lines:

```
var lat = 53.8683;
var lng = 0.5;
```

Then it worked. Strange thing is that's its been working fine for years with those vars commented out until now.

Comment: I googled it so many times but still haven't find a solution. This is also causing the browser to freeze. I was thinking it was a firefox issue, but the same thing happens also at chrome. I even created new API's but still the same.